# Chaining request on and data on events in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, promise

I am trying to merge two request's response into one single JSON
response. The function is supposed to return an array of type `[{response1JSON}, {response2JSON}]` and each response sends data stream which needs to be read

```
function getSongs() {
    const page1 = 'url1'
    const page2 = 'url2'

    let resArray = await Promise.all([
         get(page1),
         get(page2)
      ])

     let flattenedResArray = [];

     resArray[0].on('response', (res) => {
       let body = ''
       res.on('data', chunk => {
       body += chunk;
  })

      res.on('end', () => {
         flattenedResArray.push(JSON.stringify(body));
       })
     })

     resArray[1].on('response', (res) => {
       let body = ''
       res.on('data', chunk => {
         body += chunk;
       })

      res.on('end', () => {
         flattenedResArray.push(JSON.stringify(body));
       })
     }) 
   return flattenedResArray;
}
```

The `flattenedResArray` is empty because it's populated async. Things I have tried and failed

- Wrapping response around a new `Promise` object and doing a`then()`
- Chaining responses after `Promise.all(...).then(...).then(data)`

I am looking for a correct way to merge these responses using `Promise.all`.

**Note:** Both the URL's return a large JSON file which we need to stream.

Comment: Are you sure you want to confine yourself to two hard-coded urls?

Answer (score 3):

You do indeed need to call a `Promise.all` on *promises* of the two requests. It'll probably be best if you chain off of the initial promises, that way both requests can be processed at once. Because `res.on` is callback-based, not promise-based, you'll have to convert it to a `Promise`:

```
const reqToPromiseOnEnd = req => new Promise(resolve => {
  req.on('response', (res) => {
    let body = ''
    res.on('data', chunk => {
      body += chunk;
    })
    res.on('end', () => {
      resolve(JSON.stringify(body));
    })
  })
});
function getSongs() {
  const page1 = 'url1';
  const page2 = 'url2';
  return Promise.all([
    get(page1).then(reqToPromiseOnEnd),
    get(page2).then(reqToPromiseOnEnd)
  ]);
}

// example:
getSongs().then(arr => console.log(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function send(page) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // Stream code
        req.on('response', (res) => {
            let body = ''
            res.on('data', chunk => {
                body += chunk;
            })
            res.on('end', () => {
                resolve(JSON.stringify(body));
            })
        })
    });
}

function getSongs() {
    const page1 = 'url1';
    const page2 = 'url2';
    return Promise.all([
        get(page1),
        get(page2)
    ]);
}
getSongs().then(arr => console.log(arr));
```

**OR You can do using request module.** [Check This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)

```
// npm install--save request
// npm install--save request-promise

var rp = require('request-promise');

function getSongs() {
    const page1 = 'url1';
    const page2 = 'url2';
    return Promise.all([
        rp(page1),
        rp(page2)
    ]);
}

getSongs().then(arr => console.log(arr));
```